# Add delay using .each when adding class

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a simple animation in which each letter would  scale one by one. Would it be possible to have a 1 second delay when adding a  class in each div? Here is what i have done at the moment : **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/Ux328/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="animation">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>n</div>
    <div>i</div>
    <div>m</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>t</div>
    <div>e</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animate_letters{
    float:left; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:80px; 
    display:inline; 
    margin-right:5px;
    animation:fancytext 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 2, 0.35, 1.45) 0s normal none 1;

}

@keyframes fancytext{
  from {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
  }

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each( $('.animation'), function(i, animation){
        $('div', animation).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animate_letters')
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.each( $('.animation'), function(i, animation){
  $('div', animation).each(function(ii){
  var data = $(this);
  setTimeout( function () {
    $(data).addClass('animate_letters')
 }, ii * 1000);
})})});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sntZZ/)**

**Update:** also you dont need two `.each()`. you can narrow it down to one `.each()` using selector `$('.animation div')`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.animation div').each(function(ii){
 var data = $(this);
 setTimeout( function () {
  $(data).addClass('animate_letters')
 }, ii * 1000);
})});
```

**[Simplified Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v3JLP/)**

Comment: thanks for the solution. One question what does the function(ii) mean?

Comment: That is the index of looped iteration. see argument in `.each()` function

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Milind Anantwar's answer, you need to use `setTimeout`, but give each letter a different timeout:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.animation').each(function(i, animation){
        $('div', animation).each(function(j, div){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(div).addClass('animate_letters');
            }, 1000*j);
        });
    });
});
```